# Progress Dialog is paused

Tags: android, android-asynctask, async-await, background-process, progressdialog

Here it is.

Before fetching the data, creating the progress dialog and showing it now fetching data from server using volley library. It working fine. After that I need to send the data to local database as follow:

```
if (responseStatusCondition) {
   JSONArray jsonArray=response.getJSONArray("response");

   for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
      JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

      // Set the flag bit to 1 since data is already at server
      long result = bloodPressureDatabaseFragment.insertIntoBloodPressureDetails(
                          childJSONObject.getInt("systolic"),
                          childJSONObject.getInt("diastolic"),
                          childJSONObject.getLong("timestamp"),1 );
   }
}
```

Now problem is this, since the fetching part is happening in background is ok. **But the insertion data into db part is happening on the Main UI which leads to pause the progress dialog.** Is there any way to solve this problem.

I have done insertions part through the **AsynckTask**. Is there any alternative to do this task. I also read we can this through the use of Async-Await.

It is good if you please comment the reason of downvoting the question.

Comment: Try adding the data to the db in `onPostExecute()` method of your db. Or call another AsyncTask from the method.

Comment: through Async Task method I have complete the task, but I was wondering is there any other alternative to do the same task with  any other simple method.